# Beeping light fixture

Tags: electrical

I have been renting a house for a week. The light/fan woke me up beeping every 30 seconds. It continues if the light/fan is switched off. Its the middle of the night, and I am not handy. What should I do? Is it dangerous?

Comment: Call the landlord, super or owner of the house. DO NOT attempt to fix ANYTHING yourself.

Comment: I DISAGREE that my reply is a comment, it IS an answer. The ONLY correct answer. Obviously someone did not read the original question very well.

Comment: It's a terrible and wrong answer.  First, he's not fixing anything, he wants to know what's the beep and what to do about it.  Second - speaking a landlord, tenants are generally responsible for small maintenance items, such as keeping the batteries in the smoke detector fresh.  Calling the landlord will result in the landlord saying, "Change the battery".  So what should he do?  Look for the smoke detector and change the battery.

Answer (score 4):

That beeping puts me in mind of the beeping you get from a smoke detector that has a low battery.

Are you absolutely certain it's the fixture?  If so, look for some kind of battery backup - maybe there's a night-light function, or a wireless remote or something?  Or a built in smoke detector I suppose is a possibility.

Anyway - find that and change the battery.  And look around the fixture for smoke detectors, maybe your ears are tricking you on where it's coming from.

Comment: thank you Evil Greebo, I think you are correct. Being awoken in the middle of the night, alone in a strange house, I was a little confused. I could not see any smoke detectors, but this morning I noticed on in an alcove. I think the beep came from there and echoed off the light fixture, and in the absence of seeing anything else on the ceiling, I concluded it came from the light. Thank you for your answer. I appreciate your time.